# Android hang up when starting OS

Tags: android

HI all
I have develop some applications on my HTC magic device android 2.2, today I restart my device, but the OS hang up while the android logo appears for more than 1 hour fail to load the OS, Is there any way to restore at least my contacts before restoring the factory settings and wipe all the data?

I tried to use adb command, but I failed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your contacts are stored on the google cloud if your manufacturer (most likely) stored it into the google cloud. As for settings, you can be sure that this information is stored in the cloud as well. Specifically if you want to wipe user data, then its as simple as removing your SDCard and getting your provider to wipe your phone for you, look up recovery mode for your phone and this should help you solve your problem!

Good luck!